# How to get file (with japanese file name) from server using URLLoader and URLRequest in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, urlrequest

I've used URLLoader and URLRequest to get a file with japanese file name from server. However I got IO error that file is not existing (I double checked that file is existing on server and I can get other files with Latin name). Below is my code:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this._onFileLoaded);
loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, this._onSecurityError);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, this._onIOError);
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/files/メイリオ.txt");
loader.load(urlRequest);
```

Is there a way to get file from server with japanese file name using AS3?
Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: have you tried to load the file in a browser first?

Comment: I tried, but I got this error message "HTTP Status 404 - /file/%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AA.txt
The requested resource (/file/%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AA.txt) is not available."

Answer (score 0):

Try using UTF-8 [percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Try using this filename instead:

```
 var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ffiles%2F%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AA.txt");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to use escape() and encodeURI(), but not work. Because I want to get file directly without any handle at server to parse or decodeURI request, so encoded URL doesn't work with URLRequest.

Comment: Ok, I don't have any other clue... Are you sure it's the same name? I mean, these Japanese kanjis can be tricky... Try copy and paste the name. Also, what hosting are you using? [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services)?

Comment: I found the reason. I tested and run on local web server. I deployed to server, it run OK now. Thank you for your ideas, anyway.